# Google calendar notifications in double on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-calendar

I have used Calendar S, the stock calendar application on the Galaxy S3, for a few years but I recently started using the Google calendar applications instead on my Galaxy S3.

The issue I'm experiencing is that every time I receive a notification from Google Calendar, the stock application notification also appears. I always get them in double. I tried disabling the notifications in Calendar S but they are set back to enabled automatically. I also tried to remove all my calendars from the stock application but in this case it removed all calendars from the Google Calendar applications as well. It seems that the configurations of both Google Calendar and Calendar S are tied together in some way.

My question is: Is there a way to completely disable the Samsung Calendar S application in order to use Google calendar only as the main calendar application in Android ? My phone is a Galaxy S3 with the latest version of Android installed (4.4.2).

Comment: Have you tried disabling the app from the "Applications" in Settings?

Comment: I found the application details for "S Planner " in the Settings under "application manager" -> "All", however the "disable" button is greyed out and I cannot click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Highest official firmware for Galaxy S3 is up to 4.3. If your phone is running 4.4.2 maybe it's a custom ROM.
Anyway you can disable the calendar storage on the Application-> "All" tab
or just root the phone and remove the S Planner (I believe it's S planner instead of Samsung Calendar S?)

Comment: I strongly against with "disabling calendar storage". Without calendar storage, user cannot store calendar data locally.

Comment: What gives. He planned not to use  the calendar anyway.
_Is there a way to completely disable the Samsung Calendar S application in order to use Google calendar only as the main calendar application in Android_

And the Google calendar can use data from Google account.

Comment: Umm, I didn't see it that way though. He seems wanting to use only 1 calendar app (which preferably is Google calendar). Edit: yes, Google calendar can use data from Google account, but Google calendar also uses "Calendar storage" to sync/store the events. If it's disabled, then Google calendar also cannot store the events (disclaimer: I have developed a calendar app. By default, it will use "Calendar storage")

Comment: As mentioned above in a comment under the question, I found the application details for "S Planner " in the Settings under "application manager" -> "All", however the "disable" button is greyed out and I cannot click on it.

Comment: And regarding the official firmware for the Galaxy S3, my device is provided by a service provider (Telus in Canada) and their official firmware is 4.4.2 at this time.

Comment: To summarize the discussions associated to that answer, disabling the calendar storage seems to be a bad idea because Google Calendar uses it as well. And the Galaxy S3 stock "S Planner" application cannot be disabled. Therefore this does not really answers the question, but it clarified how Android manages the calendar however.